# Show contents of a bucket from amazon s3 in my visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce, amazon

[EDIT]
In My visualforce page I have got the Names of Buckets created by me on Amazon S3 . Now when i Select one of those buckets I get the list of files contained by the bucket.

```
<apex:commandLink value="{!file_name}" action="{!redirectToS3_file}"
 target="_blank">
                     <apex:param name="filename" value="{!file_name}"/> 
</apex:commandLink>
```

So with this, on clicking the File link, the content of the file is rendered on a new tab. 
I want to see the contents(i.e image in this case) of the file when I select a particular bucket. So essentially I get the redired URL from the controller method "redirectToS3_file" which returns the URL(on Amazon S3) of the File.

Comment: If you have the url of the images (and assuming they are publicly accessible), what's the issue ? (It's not entirely clear what your exact question is)

Comment: Hi Samuel, I have edited the question , let me know if it makes sense now.?

Comment: Not really, at least not to me. Are you having a problem showing images, or getting info/Data from your amazone instance to your salesforce controller ?

Comment: @Samuel, I have made an edit . Can you understand the scenario now?